# Last run date of a view and triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to find the run date of view and triggers in SQL Server? We have a script for procedures but not views and triggers. We need this to create a report of the last run date of the objects in the production.

Comment: What do you mean by "run date" for a view?? A view is **created** and then **selected from** - it's not "run" ..... (it's not procedural code, like a function, procedure or trigger that can be run.....)

Comment: So, You say there is no possible way to find the last time a view or trigger was executed/used.?

Comment: As I tried to say: a view is ***NEVER*** "executed" - you only **SELECT** from it ...

Comment: @marc_s: Ok Thank you for the information is it the same in case of triggers and functions also ?

Comment: the option you got is to look at the dynamic performance views sys.dm_exec_sessions,sys.dm_exec_connections,sys.dm_exec_sql_text to see if your view or the trigger code is being referenced

Comment: i suggest you can modify your trigger to add an insert statement to a new table, with the suser_name() and getdate() as parameters to know who has executed the trigger code and when

Comment: Trigger: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197444/last-time-of-trigger-execution

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph We are not permitted to modify the code of any of the objects. But thank for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by using a server side trace
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/setting-up-a-server-side-trace